# How to implement sign up and login using JWTs by Auth0 in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, auth0

I have a Spring Boot REST API (*Spring Boot Version 3.0.4*) that had been using HTTP Basic Authentication. I'm now moving on to JWT authentication using Auth0. So far, I have configured JWT authentication using Spring Boot's OAuth2 Resource Server using the following security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration {


    public static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/**", "POST"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error/**")
    );


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I have created an API using my Auth0 dashboard and also added the following properties in my *application. Properties*:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://<my-domain-here>.us.auth0.com/
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences=localhost:8000
auth0.audience=localhost:8000
```

I have followed [this guide by Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/01-authorization). The guide mentions how to secure endpoints but does not contain any information about how to get an access token from a client or a sign up or login process where the server associates a user in the Spring Boot API with the token.

I already have an `AppUsersController` for registering and retrieving the current user that was initially using HTTP Basic Authentication:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AppUsersController {

    private final AppUserRepository repository;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;

    public AppUsersController(AppUserRepository repository, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public AppUserInfoDto register(@RequestBody @Valid AppUserRegistrationDto registration) {

        String username = registration.email();

        if (repository.findByUsername(username).isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameAlreadyExistsException(username);
        }

        AppUser user = repository.save(registration.toUser(encoder));

        return AppUserInfoDto.fromAppUser(user);
    }


    @GetMapping
    public AppUserInfoDto current(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        return repository
                .findByUsername(user.getUsername())
                .map(AppUserInfoDto::fromAppUser)
                .orElseThrow(AppUserNotFoundException::new);
    }
}
```

The problem is most of the guides I've found demonstrate login and sign up using a self-signed public-private key pair to generate JWT Tokens where everytime the user logs in, the token is created manually using a `TokenService` and then using `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()`. Also, there are guides like [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/01-login#add-login-to-your-application) to setup login for a web application using template engines, not REST APIs.

There are examples of obtaining access tokens for clients like Angular or React. However, what if I want to login or register using curl or Postman? (My client is originally a JavaFX application making an HTTP Request to my Spring Boot API.)

How would I modify my `AppUsersController` above to support sign up and login using the configured JWT authentication and Auth0?

Here is my `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final AppUserRepository userRepository;

    public AppUserDetailsService(AppUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        AppUser user = userRepository
                .findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("The username " + username + " was not found"));

        return User.builder()
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .authorities(Collections.emptyList())
                .build();
    }
}
```

The application sources are available on GitHub:

- [Spring Boot API](https://github.com/amal-stack/notebooks-api)
- [JavaFX Client](https://github.com/amal-stack/notebooksfx)

Comment: Resource servers don't do sign up and login. They only check a given JWT. This is the wrong setup for your app. Your app seems to have the role of a web app. So you should follow the [Regular Web App Spring Boot example](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/interactive) instead.

Comment: Codo is right, triggering user login is client responsibility, not resource-server one. If you can't easily configure  your JavaFX application as an OAuth2 client (I have no experience with JavaFX, maybe it's easy, maybe not), have you considered inserting an OAuth2 client layer on your server between the front-end and your REST API? This called the BFF pattern. Sample with spring-cloud-gateway used as BFF there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff

Comment: @Codo My app is a REST API and has controllers exposing API endpoints. The example you have provided is for a web app that produces HTML pages using a template engine. I call this API from a client application and would like to have users login and signup to the API via the client. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide more context: what application will use your API? which part will provide a UI for users? Then we can describe your options.

Comment: And BTW: Auth0 provides registration UI and manages users. If you implement this in your Spring Boot application, then why do you use Auth0 in the first place?

Comment: @Codo My client is a JavaFX application that provides the login and signup interface and calls this Spring Boot API.  I've included the source code links in the question.

Comment: The best approach is probably if the JavaFX application uses a web view to host the registration/login screen. At the end, the JavaFX application has the JWT. Your Spring Boot application is configured as resource server (without any controllers for registration/login). In Auth0, use the application type "SPA" or "Native". I'm not familiar with JavaFX but it the regular web view seems to lack a few features. So the implementation is somewhat more involved. See https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/14/javafx-tutorial-oauth2-oidc

Comment: Definitely, looking at JavaFX limitations in the tutorial linked by Codo, the **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend pattern is a solution you should consider. You'll remove everything related to OAuth2 from your JavaFX app (including tokens, the requests it sends to backend will be secured with good old session cookie) and the OAuth2 client will be hosted on the server. Authorization-code initiation will be initiated by the BFF and user registration handled by the OP.

Comment: P.S. The BFF sample with `spring-cloud-gateway` I linked above is configured to use Auth0 as OIDC Provider (as well as Amazon Cognito and Keycloak). The front-end is written with Angular, but replacing it with your JavaFX shouldn't be complicated (you are interested in `login.screen.ts` and `user.service.ts` only, which should be readable for a Java developer, even if he never had a look at Angular before)

Comment: @ch4mp Will I require a separate application to serve as the BFF? Also, is it possible to have the BFF maintain a session with a Desktop JavaFX app? Shouldn't it be stateless?

Comment: BFF is not stateless, it requires session for authorization-code flow and after that to store OAuth2 tokens. Theoretically, it is possible to configure a REST API as an OAuth2 client but this is counter nature: REST APIs are much better configured as (stateless) resource servers. So yes, use a separate app and `spring-cloud-gateway` is good candidate due to its `TokenRelay` filter (replaces session cookie with OAuth2 access token stored in session)

Comment: Regarding JavaFX and sessions, I don't know. All I can say is it does not depend on the BFF, but just on the ability of your JavaFX application to handle the session cookie correctly: extract it from HTTP responses, store it somewhere (in memory should be fine) and then send it with new requests. It should also handle CSRF (extract CSRF cookie from responses and then set CSRF header or attribute for POST, PUT and DELETE requests)